# Get TreeViewItem for TreeView logical element

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem, visualtreehelper

My tree view seems like this

```
<TreeView x:Name="ArticlesTreeView" Grid.Column="0" AllowDrop="True">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate   DataType="{x:Type structure:NewsPaperDocument}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Object}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type structure:NewsPaperPage}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Object}" Foreground="#00a300" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type structure:NewsPaperTitle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Object}" Foreground="#da532c" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type structure:NewsPaperBlock}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Object}" Foreground="#2b5797" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

In `ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem` stores instance of classes `NewsPaperDocument, NewsPaperPage, etc`. How can I get `TreeViewItem` associated with `SelectedItem`? I try to use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(elem);`, but `SelectedItem` doesn't has type `DependencyObject`

**UPD1** Add simple sample, that demonstrate problem. `item` in `ArticlesTreeView_SelectedItemChanged` always `null`

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestTree.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:testTree="clr-namespace:TestTree"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="ArticlesTreeView" Grid.Column="0" AllowDrop="True" SelectedItemChanged="ArticlesTreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate   DataType="{x:Type testTree:A}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testTree:B}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#00a300" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testTree:C}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#2b5797" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestTree
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var a = new A
            {
                Name = "a",
                Children = new List<B>
                {
                    new B
                    {
                        Name = "b1",
                        Children = new List<C>
                        {
                            new C{Name = "c1"},
                            new C{Name = "c2"},
                            new C{Name = "c3"}
                        },
                    },
                    new B
                    {
                        Name = "b2",
                        Children = new List<C>
                        {
                            new C{Name = "c1"},
                            new C{Name = "c2"},
                            new C{Name = "c3"}
                        },
                    },
                    new B
                    {
                        Name = "b3",
                        Children = new List<C>
                        {
                            new C{Name = "c1"},
                            new C{Name = "c2"},
                            new C{Name = "c3"}
                        },
                    }
                }
            };
            ArticlesTreeView.ItemsSource = new List<A> { a };
        }

        private void ArticlesTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator gen = ArticlesTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
            var item = gen.ContainerFromItem(ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    internal class A
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }

        public List<B> Children { set; get; }
    }

    internal class B
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }

        public List<C> Children { set; get; }
    }

    internal class C
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem` is a `TreeViewItem`. Your problem is getting the `TreeView`? im not sure i understand your problem

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If you create you tree by manuly adding `TreeViewItem`'s to tree it wright. But I use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, and my tree creates automatucly from collection. Type of `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` is `NewsPaperBlock` or etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I got you correctly you want to retrieve the `TreeViewItem` from  the `SelectedItem`

so you can make use of `ItemContainerGenerator`

```
        ItemContainerGenerator gen = ArticlesTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
        TreeViewItem item = gen.ContainerFromItem(ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
```

**Get TreeViewItem from nested items**

due to the reason that every `TreeViewItem` has it's own `ItemContainerGenerator` so in order to find the container from the nested items we need to recurse the depth of the tree

```
    private void ArticlesTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var item = ContainerFromItem(ArticlesTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator, ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem);
    }

    private static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemContainerGenerator containerGenerator, object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem container = (TreeViewItem)containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (container != null)
            return container;

        foreach (object childItem in containerGenerator.Items)
        {
            TreeViewItem parent = containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(childItem) as TreeViewItem;
            if (parent == null)
                continue;

            container = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
            if (container != null)
                return container;

            container = ContainerFromItem(parent.ItemContainerGenerator, item);
            if (container != null)
                return container;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I try it, but `gen.ContainerFromItem(ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem)` returns **null** when `ArticlesTreeView.SelectedItem` is **not null**

Comment: this may occur due to virtualization. Important point here is that the TreeViewItem or the Container can only be retrieved when it is generated so the item should be loaded and/or in the view, if it is not the you can scroll to the item before fetching the container. just make sure that you are retrieving the Container(TreeViewItem) when you can see it otherwise there is a possibility that the Container is not yet created or has been recycled to some other item.

Comment: in the [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) all `TreeViewItems` created, and selected element visible in my View

Comment: is it possible for you to post a working sample of your code which can reproduce the issue? let's see how we can fix it for your case.

Comment: add sample in first message

Comment: updated answer to get from nested item too, previous approach was assuming direct child items of the tree