# WPF - CollectionView Refresh in TreeView with nested HierarchicalDataTemplate without losing selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Why is this so freaking hard to do, seriously :P I have the following:

```
 public BindingList<Dialogue> Dialogues { get; set; }
 public CollectionView DialoguesCollectionView { get; set; }
```

In the constructor of this ViewModel I do:

```
SubDialogues = new BindingList<SubDialogue>();
SubDialogues.ListChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SubDialogues));

    //HACK: Temporary solution...
    if (args.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded ||
        args.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
    {
        SubDialoguesCollectionView.Refresh();
    }
};

SubDialoguesCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(SubDialogues);
SubDialoguesCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Whenever I modify an item in the bound list, it gets reflected immediately. However, this does not count for Adding or Deleting items, hence I force a Refresh.

However, I also want to Refresh the list whenever the `Name` property changes, so it gets reordered accordingly, and this is where my problems began.

A TreeView in my View uses the `SubDialoguesCollectionView` as an `ItemSource` for one of its `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Whenever I select an item in the TreeView and the underlying CollectionView gets refreshed for whatever reason, it loses the selection and instead jumps to the parent of the whole list.

I don't want this to happen, I want to retain the selection of the item, even if its offset got changed due to the reordering. Could anyone assist me in figuring out how I would get this to work how I want? I've literally tried everything: SortableBindingList, Behaviors, moving items instead of doing a refresh, the list goes on. I'm starting to grow gray hairs! :P

If there are other methods I might be overlooking, I would love to hear about them too. All I want in the end is a list that reorders itself when the `Name` property of any bound object changes, but without losing the selection of that object in the TreeView.

---

As requested a copy/paste version of how my codebase is setup (albit simplified and flattened): https://gist.github.com/LennardF1989/59a42c7be474061f14bd

I left out my failed attempt described above, this is the state it was in before I attempted anything.

Comment: You need an attached behaviour to expose the otherwise read-only SelectedItem, post an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: Like a ZIP with a working project or just copy/paste code?

Comment: Pasting here is fine, just something that will compile and show the issue to make sure I'm correctly understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Updated question with link: https://gist.github.com/LennardF1989/59a42c7be474061f14bd

Comment: With bindings, the update method doesn't always work.  Sometimes it is necessary to set the Binding to null and then set the Binding back to the list object.

Comment: @LennardFonteijn ok, so just to be clear you want it so that all the elements in a given node are sorted alphabetically and get automatically re-sorted as the user edits the name without de-selecting the currently selected item, correct?

Comment: @MarkFeldmanThat's totally correct :) What happens in my actual program is that because of the SelectedItemChanged event the PropertyGrid (in the example substituted for a textbox bound to Name) loses its selection, which is highly annoying behavior.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Did you get round to working on an example yet? :)

Comment: Sorry Lennard, you left out the space between "@MarkFeldman" and "That's" so I never got the notification that you'd answered. Will get back to you soon...

Comment: @MarkFeldman Oh wow, that I didn't spot that. Thank you!

Comment: @LennardFonteijn answer given below, let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually several issues at play here. To be perfectly honest the main problem is that you're not using data-binding properly, if you were using something like MVVM then you would be manipulating view models and the UI would fall into line. As it is, there are some complex interactions going on internally with the view elements.

Before going further I'll just point out a couple of changes I've made to your code.

- Don't use BindingList, it doesn't scale well at all; I've replaced yours with ObservableCollections.
- You're already importing MVVM Lite so you may as well use ViewModelBase instead of declaring your own BaseViewModel. You'll still have problems with MainWindow of course due to C# not supporting multiple-inheritence, but then there shouldn't be any code in MainWindow anyway ;)
- In the interest of steering the code towards better data-binding I've replaced the function that updates SelectedObject with an attached behavior, the source code is below. (This isn't really related to the question so I hope you'll forgive me this one indulgence).
- I've created a second field called SortedDialogues which is the CollectionViewSource for Dialogues. I've also added a SortDescription to order by "Name". So Dialogues can be left alone, you bind to SortedDialogues instead and whenever something (i.e. a Dialogue name) changes you call the SortedDialogues' `Refresh()` member to update the sorting.
- I've only done this for the Dialogues, I'll let you apply it to the Quests etc.

Now, what's happening is that the TreeView maintains an internal list of TreeViewItems, each of which have a `IsSelected` flag (in an MVVM app you would bind these to a property in their corresponding view model). When you refresh the sorted list the TreeView responds by re-creating the TreeViewItems for the relevant sub-tree from scratch. The currently selected TreeViewItem gets detached from the TreeView, so the framework responds by selecting the parent node instead i.e. the Quest. Ordinarily you could call `treeview.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)` to get the new TreeView from the item, but this doesn't work with HierarchicalDataTemplates due to the dynamic way in which the nodes are created at runtime. The trick is to thus traverse the TreeView's hierarchy manually looking for the node with the selected value.

Here's the new code:

```
public interface INameable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Quest : ViewModelBase, INameable
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Dialogue> _Dialogues;
    public ObservableCollection<Dialogue> Dialogues
    {
        get { return this._Dialogues; }
        set { this._Dialogues = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ICollectionView _SortedDialogues;
    public ICollectionView SortedDialogues
    {
        get { return this._SortedDialogues; }
        set { this._SortedDialogues = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    // this is actually a bit messy, I'll leave it to you to find a cleaner way of doing this
    public Func<object> GetSelected;
    public Action<object> SetSelected;

    public Quest()
    {
        Dialogues = new ObservableCollection<Dialogue>();

        this.SortedDialogues = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Dialogues);
        this.SortedDialogues.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }

    public void AddDialogue(Dialogue dlg)
    {
        this.Dialogues.Add(dlg);
        dlg.PropertyChanged += Dlg_PropertyChanged;
        SortDialogues();
    }

    private void Dlg_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SortDialogues();
    }

    private void SortDialogues()
    {
        var selected = GetSelected(); // get currently selected item
        this.SortedDialogues.Refresh(); // bam! treeviewitmes get destroyed.
        SetSelected(selected); // so reselect it immediately
    }
}

public class Dialogue : ViewModelBase, INameable
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}

public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private object _selectedObject = new object();
    public object SelectedObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedObject = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Quest> Quests
    {
        get { return _quests; }
        set
        {
            _quests = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Quest> _quests;        

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Quests = new ObservableCollection<Quest>();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddQuest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Quests.Add(new Quest
        {
            Name = "Quest",
            GetSelected = () => this.SelectedObject,
            SetSelected = (selected) => {
                ItemContainerGenerator gen = _treeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
                TreeViewItem item = ContainerFromItem(gen, selected);
                if (item != null)
                    item.IsSelected = true;
            }
            ,
        });
    }

    private void AddDialogue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_treeView.SelectedItem is Quest)
        {
            var dlg = new Dialogue
            {
                Name = "Dialogue"
            };
            (_treeView.SelectedItem as Quest).AddDialogue(dlg);
        }
    }

    // courtesy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859511/get-treeviewitem-for-treeview-logical-element
    private static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemContainerGenerator containerGenerator, object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem container = (TreeViewItem)containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (container != null)
            return container;

        foreach (object childItem in containerGenerator.Items)
        {
            TreeViewItem parent = containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(childItem) as TreeViewItem;
            if (parent == null)
                continue;

            container = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
            if (container != null)
                return container;

            container = ContainerFromItem(parent.ItemContainerGenerator, item);
            if (container != null)
                return container;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

And here's the XAML for the TreeView:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="_treeView" behaviors:TreeViewHelper.SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">

            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Project" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Quests}" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Quests" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testApplication:Quest}" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedDialogues, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testApplication:Dialogue}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.Resources>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
```

And finally the behaviour that binds the currently selected item, it exists in various forms around the net so I don't know where it originally came from:

```
public class TreeViewHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<DependencyObject, TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior> behaviors = new Dictionary<DependencyObject, TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior>();

    public static object GetSelectedItem(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItem(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(TreeViewHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(obj is TreeView))
            return;

        if (!behaviors.ContainsKey(obj))
            behaviors.Add(obj, new TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior(obj as TreeView));

        TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior view = behaviors[obj];
        view.ChangeSelectedItem(e.NewValue);
    }

    private class TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior
    {
        TreeView view;
        public TreeViewSelectedItemBehavior(TreeView view)
        {
            this.view = view;
            view.SelectedItemChanged += (sender, e) => SetSelectedItem(view, e.NewValue);
        }

        internal void ChangeSelectedItem(object p)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)view.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(p);
            // item will be null for HierarchicalDataTemplates
            if (item != null)
                item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! For that, thank you. I'm aware I'm not really implementing MVVM properly, I have no excuse for this :P Now a few questions: if I would bind the IsSelected to a ViewModel as you mentioned, would I still need the attached behavior, or would the problem solve itself? Regarding BindingList: The example I gave you was pretty simple, but I have complex Models behind the TreeViewItems which other parts of the UI have to react to. The BindingList propagated those for me, what's the alternative here? Since ObservableCollection basically only propagates list-changes, not model-changes?

Comment: The behaviour is only there so you can bind the currently selected item to SelectedObject, if each TreeViewItem is bound to a view model, and you give that view model a `IsSelected` property which you bind to the TreeViewItem's `IsSelected` then no, you won't need the behaviour. You just work with the view models themselves.

Comment: Regarding your second question, your models and your view models should ideally be separate. So you'd have a model with all the data and then you have a corresponding view model which exposes the model's properties with it's own versions which do INPC. The VM also has any additional properties needed for the view e.g. the `IsSelected` property I mention above. Everything in the view binds to the view model, not the view, so everything gets updated whenever anything changes (and of course those changes propagate down to the model as well). BindingList shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: Ugh, I shot myself in the foot. I already have such a setup with Models, ViewModels and Views. At least I would have still needed the piece of code you provided to find the item to reselect after Refresh, right!? Or would that have also not been required if I had added the IsSelected?

Comment: Nope, isn't required. If the IsSelect bindings are set up correctly then the new TreeViewItems that get created in response to the Refresh() call get bound to their corresponding view models and set their initial IsSelected visual state accordingly. It's yet another example of how it pays to use data binding, even when you're not doing full-blown MVVM. It's how WPF was designed to be used.

Comment: I feel so silly. The stupidest thing is I have it as a TODO in my code, I just didn't assume it would solve my problem. Ah well, thank you very very much for your explanations!