# MVVM Correct place to interact with a UI element or alternative method

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a search method which searches a TreeView's data source, loads any branches which have not yet been loaded, selects the matching branch and displays the related items in a ListView. I now want to make sure the selected item is visible in the TreeView using `TreeViewItem`'s `BringIntoView()` method. However I've read that directly interacting with the View in your View Model breaks the MVVM pattern. I have the following methods (Thanks to pushpraj for the `ContainerFromItem` method from this question - [Get TreeViewItem for TreeView logical element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859511/get-treeviewitem-for-treeview-logical-element/24859863#24859863)):

```
public static void SelectedItemChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var tv = (TreeView)sender;
    var item = ContainerFromItem(tv.ItemContainerGenerator, e.NewValue);
    item.BringIntoView();
}

private static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemContainerGenerator containerGenerator, object item)
{
    TreeViewItem container = (TreeViewItem)containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    if (container != null)
        return container;

    foreach (object childItem in containerGenerator.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem parent = containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(childItem) as TreeViewItem;
        if (parent == null)
            continue;

        container = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
        if (container != null)
            return container;

        container = ContainerFromItem(parent.ItemContainerGenerator, item);
        if (container != null)
            return container;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I assume placing this in the View Model would break the MVVM pattern. So should this be in the Code Behind? or is that supposed to remain empty? Otherwise, is there an alternative method to achieve this which is more suited to the MVVM pattern?

Comment: This method can be very slow BTW, because it iterates over *all* items of the container generator. If you're using the UI virtualization, that will also realize all virtual items. To your question: such kind of things should be placed in the view. There is no issue with that: this method doesn't operate with any concrete model or viewmodel types. You could also make a behavior out of that (and again, place it in the view).

Comment: You can do anything you like in the view when it is limited to **view logic** - MVVM is not "no code behind at all" but "not all in code behind"

Comment: Thank you both for the information. @dymanoid You mentioned this method can be very slow, which makes sense. The problem I had, is my model needs to inherit from Caliburn.Micro's `PropertyChangedBase`, so I'm not able to inherit from TreeViewItem to get access to the `BringIntoView()` method. Is there a faster/better way to do this?